# stored username and password, is it visible to anyone with a .apk decompiler?

Tags: android

I am trying to use stored username and password to connect to a web service from android app code, is it visible to anyone who can decompile my .apk file please help?

Comment: are you using SharedPreferences?

Comment: In which place u r storing your username and password?

Comment: no I don't, just hardcoded...

Comment: Instead of storing credentials in clear-text, I would suggest to use Hashing

Comment: encode it to MD5 ans save it

Comment: is hashing a bulletproof solution to this?

Comment: You should store your username and password in encrypted form. so no one can decrypt it easily.

Comment: thanks for the answers I think some kind of encryption is the way to go, and obfuscating too.

Comment: MD5 can be colluded and there are examples on the Internet that proved so. I would suggest you use SHA-1 hash - much harder to crack.

Comment: does Google Android officially recommend anything on this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing a credential in plain text. Ever. If your user logs in, then you should store the cookie or session key but not the password itself. If it's credentials for a web service and you need it encoded, you should use API Keys instead of a password.

Comment: thanks OrhanC1 I'm pretty new to Android Development should look for some resources that explain API keys, if you can provide a link, much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, @eMM. Whether you get an API Key depends on the API's implementation. For example, if I were to log into a web page that stores a cookie or session key, I would store that instead of the password.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the credentials in the memory then one cannot directly get those by decompiling. But instead they can see the way you are storing the values. Like if you are storing it in SharedPreferences they can see the keys for the values and they can regenerate the apk and get the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) for obsfucate your .classes files, and store your credentials there. It is a bit dificult for use it, but the results is excelent.

The classes that you don't want to obfuscate, you can use:

```
-keep public class <MyClass>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: both obfuscating and encryption seems to be the solution, thanks.